# Trigger "Set" when changed class object property C#

Tags: c#

If I have a custom class `Vector3` and I have a class object `Myobject` that use the `vector3` class as a property and when I set a new vector 
`myobject.pos = new vector3(x,y,z);` the `set` will trigger in this case `Debug.Log("set")` as expected but If I instead of creating a new vector I only want to change `x` but still have `set` triggered I would want to do `myobject.pos.x = x` but this will not trigger the `set` in `MyObject` but the `set` in my `vector3` class for x is there any way of fixing this so `set` in `MyObject` triggers when I change only the "*sub property*" x of the `vector3`.

```
public class MyObject{
        private Vector3 p_pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        public Vector3 pos
        {
            get { return (p_pos); }
            set
            {
                Debug.Log("set");
                p_pos = value;
            }
        }
}
```

The only way I can think of doing it is to create a separate method in `MyObject` class like this `MyObject.SetPosX(x)`:

```
public void SetPosX(double _x)
{
    Debug.Log("set");
    p_pos.x = _x;
}
```

But It is not a very clean way of doing it so would prefer another solution.

Comment: What's wrong with that solution? It seems perfectly fine. I don't see how else you would do it.

Comment: @AaronHolland Because then I have two ways of changing the x component both `MyObject.pos.x = x` and `MyObject.SetPosX(x)` but only the SetPosX will correctly update things in the class object, so the risk is that `MyObject.pos.x = x` is accidentally used in some places and it will not trigger certain methods in the object correctly updating it, and that will be a pain to debug

Comment: Then I guess you would need to remove the getter / setter for the whole Vector and implement a GetX, SetX,, GetY, SetY, GetZ and SetZ on your object (you could/should probably just use properties)

Comment: @AaronHolland Then I rather have two ways of setting x and take the risk of using the wrong one.

Comment: A thing called Vector3 should probably be an immutable struct. This isn't a problem in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it could be implemented in a more structured way is to allow Vector3 notify someone when a property has been changed. My object class would be listening to and react when necessary.
In the code you provide it looks like overhead but in fact, it depends on a real situation.

Code is below

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        myObject.p_pos = vector3;
        myObject.p_pos.X = 5;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class Vector3
{
    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x; Y = y; Z = z;
    }

    private double _x;
    private double _y;
    private double _z;

    public double X
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public double Y
    {
        get
        {
            return _y;
        }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public double Z
    {
        get
        {
            return _z;
        }
        set
        {
            _z = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    private Vector3 _p_pos = null;

    public Vector3 p_pos { get
        {
            return _p_pos;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_p_pos != null)
                _p_pos.PropertyChanged-= _p_pos_PropertyChanged;
            _p_pos = value;
            _p_pos.PropertyChanged += _p_pos_PropertyChanged;

        }
    }

    private void _p_pos_PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("_p_pos_PropertyChanged");
    }
}
```

The other way which could be more preferable is to make vector3 immutable so each time you need to change the value you have to create the new instance of vector3. This should allow you to stay with the lightweight version of vector3 and still have control over its value.

Answer (score 0):

As the reason why it works like that seems not to be answered, I'll give it a shot.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Vector3 _v = 0;
    public Vector3 V { get { return _v; } set { _v = value; } }

    void DoSomething ()
    {
        V = new Vector3 (2, 0, 0); // This will trigger 'set'.
        V.x = 2;                   // This will not.
    }
}
```

If you have a Vector3 property and set its specific values, you set the values within the Vector3 class itself, but do not affect the assignment/reference to the said Vector3. In order to change its x value, you do not set a new or other Vector3 for 'V'. One way to circumvent that, as you already figured out, is simply to use a method to change the values of 'V' and trigger your extra code. Another one would be to have your own class which triggers your extra code when its properties are changed (for Vector3 not quite possible).

If you only want to track changes to Vector3s, you'd have to create something like a value Watcher class, which would be triggered in update to detect changes to values you want to track. To create this could be quite sophisticated and would involve lambda expressions and generics at least, possibly even an entire code structure in Unity by using a global base class for everything that shall inherit from MonoBehavior.